# animated table of content for android application book

Tags: android, list, android-listview, android-animation, expandablelistview

I want design a book application in android...
in the table of content in start of book, It must show only **main titles** and when a user click on the one title, the **rest of titles** must **shift down** to get place **to subset of clicked title to be shown**...the subset of clicked title must be shown with some **indent** that show it is the subset of which title...
I am beginner,**Can any one guide me what topics or special component can do it in better shape?**
I search animation list view , but when I import the founded source code in eclipse , it have not src segment,and instead have java segment...
I am not familiar with such projects,Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) should solve the problem you are having.

Comment: thaaanks a lot dear prats100892!  It is what I wanted...but the Appearance of ExpandableListView seems simple and I want my table of content  has some interesting animations or graphic...however I am beginner so is it possible that I give animation to ExpandableListView ?  and another problem is that the subset must be showed with some indent ...what must I do?

Comment: you can use this library. Should work pretty well for your needs https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView